# Applet does not show up in browser

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have the following applet: http://s1.picofile.com/file/6922766596/Game.jar.html

and my applet before jar :http://s1.picofile.com/file/6923855130/Game_III_Applet.7z.html

I have embedded it as follows in my HTML page:

```
<applet code="FrameS.class" archive="Game.jar" width=1000 height=800></applet>
```

However, nothing shows in my MSIE browser. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: i forget to write that my html ends with</applet>

Comment: No, you forgot to read the code formatting rules. You need to indent code with 4 spaces. I have swept the question. There was a lot of noise in there. You would otherwise only have received downvotes. Just ask the question straight and the smart way. Little effort, lot of favour for yourself and us.

Comment: you are true!i am realy sorry dear..

Comment: **Cross-post** of [problem with view jar applet on browser](http://www.coderanch.com/t/544558/Applets/java/view-jar-applet-browser).

Comment: thanks Andrew..you are very legal politely:&

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: 
    access denied (java.io.FilePermission back.jpg read)
```

Applets should use URLs to access their resources.  The resource can be in a Jar file (such as the 4.7 meg `Game.jar`) that is on the applet's run time class-path (i.e. mentioned in the archive attribute) or loose on the same server as the applet (or the applet's codebase).

In the first case, an URL can be formed using ..

```
URL urlToPic = this.getClass().getResource("images/back.jpg");
```

.. where the image is located in the `images` path of the Jar.

In the 2nd case, an URL can be formed relative to the codebase or document base of the applet.  E.G.

```
URL urlToPic = new URL(this.getDocumentBase(), "images/back.jpg");
```

.. where the image is in the `images` sub-directory of the directory containing the applet.

The methods that accept a `File` parameter will often also accept an `InputStream` or `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot test it when you provide just the `.jar` package

please provide more, or solve it yourself by looking into java error console

for example I got this exception, saying I'm missing `back.jpg` image resource

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(DeployAWTUtil.java:116)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Plugin2Manager.java:3542)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3073)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1498)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission back.jpg read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(SunToolkit.java:871)
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(SunToolkit.java:885)
at apple.awt.CToolkit.getImage(CToolkit.java:934)
at FrameS.<init>(FrameS.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$13.run(Plugin2Manager.java:3061)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:647)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: hi..no this applet have not this exception .i wrote that myself for expicitely i send the applet file(no jar file)http://s1.picofile.com/file/6923855130/Game_III_Applet.7z.html

Comment: Applet has this exception when you provide incomplete package of source files, it has non-caught exception when trying to load inexistent file (which you obviously haven't provided)

Comment: http://s1.picofile.com/file/6923855130/Game_III_Applet.7z.html this is my apple.this realy havent any exception and run good..i make jur with e-clipse

Answer (score -1):

Please use the object tag when embedding applets in IE , here is a php function which outputs applet embedding code based on a browser you will see different browsers are handled differently -

```
function getApplet($jarFile,$className,$params = array(),$width=1,$height=1,$name='japplet')
{
$retVal = "";

$useApplet = 0;
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (stristr($user_agent, "konqueror") || stristr($user_agent, "macintosh") || stristr($user_agent, "opera")) {
    $useApplet = 1;
    $retVal = sprintf('<applet name="%s" id="%s" archive="%s" code="%s" width="%s" height="%s" MAYSCRIPT >',$name,$name,$jarFile,$className,$width,$height);
} else {
    if (strstr($user_agent, "MSIE")) {
        $retVal = sprintf('<object  name="%s" id="%s" classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" style="border-width:0;" codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4_1-windows-i586.cab#version=1,4,1"  width= "%s" height= "%s">',$name,$name,$width,$height);
    } else {
        $retVal = sprintf('<object  name="%s" id="%s" type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1" width= "%s" height= "%s">',$name,$name,$width,$height);
    }

    $params['archive'] = $jarFile;
    $params['code'] = $className;
    $params['mayscript'] = 'true';
    $params['scriptable'] = 'true';
    $params['name'] = $name;

}

foreach ($params as $var=>$val)
{
    $retVal .= sprintf('<param name="%s" value="%s">',$var,$val);
}

$retVal .= 'It appears you do not have Java installed or it is disabled on your system.<br />
                Please download it <a href="http://www.java.com/getjava/" class="link" target="_blank">here</a>';
if ($useApplet == 1) {
    $retVal .= '</applet>';
} else {
    $retVal .= '</object>';
}

return $retVal;
}
```

Object tag is what you need while embedding you applet.

Comment: *"Object tag is what you need while embedding you applet."* -1 This is wrong, and has nothing to do with why the applet is failing.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html

I assumed it was failing in MSIE only .

Comment: i say again this is my application and it has not any failure on run on e clipse.all problem do when i want to run application on browser.http://s1.picofile.com/file/6923855130/Game_III_Applet.7z.html